# Vue js vee validate password confirmation always false

Tags: validation, vue.js, vuejs2, vee-validate

I'm trying to use vee validate to verify the password using this code.

```
<div>
    <input type="password"
           placeholder="Password"
           v-model="password"
           v-validate="'required|min:6|max:35|confirmed'"
           name="password" />
</div>
<div>
    <span>{{ errors.first('password') }}</span>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="password"
           placeholder="Confirm password"
           v-model="confirmPassword"
           v-validate="'required|target:password'"
           name="confirm_password" />
</div>
<div>
    <span>{{ errors.first('confirm_password') }}</span>
</div>
```

But it always says **The password confirmation does not match.**
What went wrong in my code?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Your password input must have `ref="password"` - that's how vee-validate finds the target:

`<input v-validate="'required'" ... ref="password">` (Thanks, [Ryley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/312208/ryley)).

> confirmed:{target} - Input must have the same value as the target
>   input, specified by {target} as the target field’s name.

Also, there's an error with your Vee Validate syntax, change `target:` to `confirmed:`

`v-validate="'required|target:password'"`

should be

`v-validate="'required|confirmed:password'"`

Have a look at the basic example below, it will check for two things:

- Does the second input field have any input value?
- If yes, does the second input value match the first input value?

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!'
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 15px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  width: 60%;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vee-validate/2.1.1/vee-validate.js"></script>
<script>
  Vue.use(VeeValidate);
</script>


<div id="app">

  <form id="demo">

    <!-- INPUTS -->
    <div class="input-group">
      <h4 id="header"> Enter Password</h4>

      <div class="input-fields">
        <input v-validate="'required'" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" ref="password">

        <input v-validate="'required|confirmed:password'" name="password_confirmation" type="password" placeholder="Password, Again" data-vv-as="password">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- ERRORS -->
    <div class="alert alert-danger" v-show="errors.any()">
      <div v-if="errors.has('password')">
        {{ errors.first('password') }}
      </div>
      <div v-if="errors.has('password_confirmation')">
        {{ errors.first('password_confirmation') }}
      </div>
    </div>

  </form>
</div>
```

Further reading: https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/guide/rules.html#confirmed

Comment: Also, your password input must have `ref="password"` as that's how vee-validate finds the "target"

Comment: @Ryley Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. very helpful answer . =)

Comment: v-validate can find target from name

Comment: @BennettDams thanks a lot. This helped me. could you please *bold* the ref thing please, that was really crucial in my case. Special thanks to ryley guy - u my man!.

Comment: May I ask you to have a look at a VeeValidate related question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59488066/bootstrapvue-veevalidate-show-an-extra-error-message-when-form-is-invalid ?

Answer (score 7):

Below code works for me: https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/advanced/cross-field-validation.html#targeting-other-fields

```
<template>
  <ValidationObserver>
    <ValidationProvider rules="required|password:@confirm" v-slot="{ errors }">
      <input type="password" v-model="password" />
      <span>{{ errors[0] }}</span>
    </ValidationProvider>

    <ValidationProvider name="confirm" rules="required" v-slot="{ errors }">
      <input type="password" v-model="confirmation" />
      <span>{{ errors[0] }}</span>
    </ValidationProvider>
  </ValidationObserver>
</template>

<script>
import { extend } from 'vee-validate';

extend('password', {
  params: ['target'],
  validate(value, { target }) {
    return value === target;
  },
  message: 'Password confirmation does not match'
});

export default {
  data: () => ({
    password: '',
    confirmation: ''
  })
};
</script>
```

Comment: This works Thank your for more information `https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/advanced/cross-field-validation.html#targeting-other-fields`

Answer (score 0):

On **Vee-validate 3.x.x** another way of doing it is:

```js
<template>
  <ValidationObserver>
    <ValidationProvider vid="password" rules="required" v-slot="{ errors }">
      <input type="password" v-model="password" />
      <span>{{ errors[0] }}</span>
    </ValidationProvider>

    <ValidationProvider name="confirm" rules="required|confirmed:password" v-slot="{ errors }">
      <input type="password" v-model="confirmation" />
      <span>{{ errors[0] }}</span>
    </ValidationProvider>
  </ValidationObserver>
</template>

<script>
import { extend } from 'vee-validate';

extend("confirmed", {
  ...confirmed,
  message: "The password does not match",
});

export default {
  data: () => ({
    password: '',
    confirmation: ''
  })
};
</script>
```

Something import to notice is the `vid` prop on the first validation provider. It will **NOT** work without it.